# Find Delphi source codes to parse printf format specifier

Tags: delphi

I want to write a function in Delphi to check if two strings contain the same list of format specifiers. One string is in English, and another is translated into another language.

For example,

string1 = 'The number is %d.'

string2 = '这个数字是%d.'

Sometimes, the translator will make a mistake and modify the format specifier, like below:

string2 = '这个数字是% d.'

So I want to write a function to perform the check automatically. The function needs to **collect all the format specifiers** in the string. Since there are many cases to consider, I want to modify the existing source codes instead of writing from the beginning.

I have already done so by modifying Delphi's WideFormatBuf function to support Delphi strings.

Now to **support C++ strings**, I am looking for existing Delphi codes to parse [printf format specifier](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) so that I can also modify based on them(my code is Delphi)

wsprintf in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471946/sprintf-in-delphi) does not work for my case, as it does not contain the actual source codes in parsing the format specifiers.

Comment: `%(?'flags'[-+ #0])?(?'width'(?:\d+|\*))?(?'precision'\.(?:\d+|\*))?(?'length'(?:h|hh|l|ll|j|z|t|L))?(?'specifier'[diuoxXfFeEgGaAcspn%])`

Comment: I don't know any Delphi `printf` implementation, but you can check out [GLibC implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c;h=6d6d96e8005ebef39d79a940c6e5afc8341f1456;hb=HEAD) in C

Comment: @PeterWolf, ´printf´ as well as ´sprintf´ are part of *System.Win.Crtl.pas*, but they are declared external, linked to *msvcrt.dll*. Nevertheless they can be used from Delphi on Windows platforms.

Comment: @UweRaabe That's correct, but OP looks for Delphi implementation.

Comment: @PeterWolf, Where do you find the regexp? I think a regexp does work for my case and it is much simpler than to modify the source codes.

Comment: I wrote it myself ;)

Comment: @PeterWolf, Thank you very much.